# Can't get 400 Bad request properly

Tags: angular, .net-core

I'm trying to handling errors with user authentication, and when user register new account but the username already exist, It should throw 400 Bad request error.

So this is my register method in `AuthController.cs`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult>Register(UserForRegisterDto 
                                                   userForRegisterDto)
    {
    userForRegisterDto.username = userForRegisterDto.username.ToLower();

        if(await _repo.UserExists(userForRegisterDto.username)) 
        {
            return BadRequest("Username already exists !");
        }

        var userToCreate = new User
        {
            Username = userForRegisterDto.username
        };

     var createdUser = await _repo.Register(userToCreate, 
                                            userForRegisterDto.password);

        return StatusCode(201);
    }
```

in `register.component.ts`:

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
@Output() cancelRegister = new EventEmitter();
model: any = {};
constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }
ngOnInit() {}

register() {
    this.authService.register(this.model).subscribe(() => {
  console.log('create successed');
}, error => {  
  console.log(error);
});
}

cancel() {
   this.cancelRegister.emit(false);
    console.log('canceled');
 }
}
```

in `register.component.html`:

```
<form #registerForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="register()">
<h2 class="text-center text-primary">Sign Up</h2>
<hr>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" required name="username" 
    [(ngModel)]="model.username" placeholder="Username">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" required name="password" 
[(ngModel)]="model.password" placeholder="Password">
</div>

<div class="form-group text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Register</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" 
    (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
</form>
```

To send error from front-end, I created `Exceptions.cs` which will hold error in the header of the fetch API:

```
 public static class Exceptions
{
    public static void AddApplicationError(this HttpResponse response, 
                                            string message)
    {
        response.Headers.Add("Application-Error", message);

        response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", 
                                         "Application-Error");

        response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    }
}
```

To catch errors, I created error.interceptor.ts which will handle errors sent from the backend:

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
  Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
        catchError(error => {
    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {

        const applicationError = error.headers.get('Application-Error');
                if (applicationError) {
                    console.error(applicationError);
                    return throwError(applicationError);
                }
     const serverError = error.error.errors; 

                let modalStateErrors = '';
                if (serverError && typeof serverError === 'object' ) {
                    for (const key in serverError) {
                        if (serverError[key]) {
                            modalStateErrors += serverError[key] + `\n`;
                        }
                    }
                }

    return throwError(modalStateErrors || serverError || 'Server Error');
            }
        })
    );
    }
}
//add this method to provider in app.module.ts to get everything work 
export const ErrorProvider = { 
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: ErrorInterceptor,
    multi: true
};
```

The `serverError` will hold the all the exceptions and register method in register component will display errors on the console, everything is working as I expected except the 400 Bad request defined in register method in `AuthController`. Now It's return "Server Error" but what I expected is "Username already exists!"

I'm using .net-core 2.2 and totally new to angular. I will appreciate any idea that help me to solve this problem :-)

Comment: yes it is, but I already handled 400 status with the return string "username already exists!"  so I want the angular application's console return the same string, not "Server Error" which is some unhandle exceptions.

Comment: In your interceptor, before this     if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse)
please try to do console.log(error )  and look at the HTTP status

Comment: yeah, I can find the error string "username already exists" in HttpErrorResponse

Comment: So here your  there now, this is the cause => return throwError(modalStateErrors || serverError || ''Server Error'');

Comment: try changing it to return throwError(modalStateErrors || serverError || error.error );

Comment: Many thanks for pointing it out !! I sometimes get silly in this situation :-)

Comment: You are welcome, i understand you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After revision of the code,

The problem was in `interceptor` due to the return statement, an it has been solved with :

```
@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
  Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req).pipe(
        catchError(error => {
    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {

        const applicationError = error.headers.get('Application-Error');
                if (applicationError) {
                    console.error(applicationError);
                    return throwError(applicationError);
                }
     const serverError = error.error.errors; 

                let modalStateErrors = '';
                if (serverError && typeof serverError === 'object' ) {
                    for (const key in serverError) {
                        if (serverError[key]) {
                            modalStateErrors += serverError[key] + `\n`;
                        }
                    }
                }

    return throwError(modalStateErrors || serverError || error.error ); 
            }
        })
    );
    }
}
```